# Restrict certian features in the AndroidManifest

Tags: android, android-manifest

Is it possible to restrict certain features of the Android Application to certain API versions of the Android, by using the same Android Manifest file. I have a generic android manifest file for API versions 10 to 21. From that I want APIs from 18 onwards some other features. Is it possible ?

The RBLService, I just want to enable for API > 18.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <service
        android:name=".redbear.RBLService"
        android:enabled="true" />
</application>
```

Comment: you have to do it programatically

Comment: @VivekMishra no way to make some restrictions in the manifest ?

Comment: Please explain, in detail, what "restrict certain features" means.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have updated the question.

Comment: In your case, compared to my answer on the duplicate question, your `bool` resource would be `false` in `res/values/` and `true` in `res/values-v18/`.